# how to find if set of points is part of circle - a curve

Tags: geometry

Lets say that I have a random polygon that can have any shape. Polygon is made of points that I'm interested in.

1. How can I check whether given polygon iis simpliefied circle?
2. How can I check whether some part of this polygon - some set of points - has a shape of curve (is part of a circle)? - E.g. upper case D letter - (`D`) with solid fill - you can say its half of a  cicle, but how would you check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any three points determine a circle.  See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16209/how-to-determine-the-center-and-radius-of-a-circle-given-three-points-in-3d#16210) for how to determine this.  Then, you can check if all the other points are on that circle.

Your second question is vague, in light of the above -- any three points are on a circle.  If you want to check if four consecutive points are on a circle, use the above algorithm.

Comment: Great, thank you. With some buffer (that is relative to polygon's area) I'll be able to find if given polygon is "kind of" circle.